# Add "changing..." to a button as it changes state using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a button that uses Javascript to toggle a **complete boolean** from true to false and vice versa.

I am looking to change the inner text to **changing...** as it goes from one state to the other.
I have added sleep to the method in controller, and have tried adding a `data: { disable_with: "changing..."}` but this breaks the change of text on completion.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**meetings_controller.rb**

```
def completed
  sleep 1
  @meeting.toggle!(:complete)
end
```

link in **index.rb**

```
<div id="meeting-<%= meeting.id %>">
  <%= link_to "#{ meeting.complete ? 'Already completed' : 'Mark as complete'  }",  completed_meeting_path(meeting), method: :patch, remote: :true, class: "btn btn-#{ meeting.complete ? 'success' : 'warning' }"  %>
</div>
```

**completed.js.erb**

```
<% if @meeting.complete == true %>
  $("#meeting-<%= @meeting.id %> a").html('Already completed').removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-success');
<% else %>
  $("#meeting-<%= @meeting.id %> a").html('Mark as complete').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-warning');
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [click event](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to the button:

```js
// some_file.js
$("#meeting_container").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  $(e.target).html("changing...").prop("disabled", true);
});
// Example code, may need to tweak a bit
```